# press back button android when change scene close the game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, back-button, scene

i have 3 scenes 
scene : `mainmenu`, `levelselect`, `loadlevel`

when i press back button on ..
`mainmenu` -> game exit
`levelselect` -> back to `mainmenu`
`loadlevel` -> `levelselect`

when i press back button on transition scene the game exit
transition from `mainmenu` to `levelselect` -> game exit
transition from `levelselect` to `loadlevel` -> game exit

i don't know what happend in here.

sorry if repost

Comment: Post your code and edit your question, it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found the answer
this error happend because bug of unity 4.3
override function `backPress` will not work
thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you mean "scenes" is your activities and "press back button" is your physical back button. Anyway, why dont you try to override your "physical" back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

                Intent i = new Intent(Activity.this,
                        OtherActivity.class);
                //set this flag to avoid undesired transictions between activities
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(i);

    }
```

Comment: can you help me, how to use that code in unity c# monodevelop?